# Meaning of さてと and general comprehension

Tags: reading-comprehension

The context: Maruko and her mum prepared food and bath salts as a new year's gift for Maruko's grandad (ともぞう) and grandma. But dad (ヒロシ) has just eaten all the food. Maruko protests and dad says:

> 「いいんじゃよ。まる子、わしのことなんて気にしなくても...」
>   Dad: "It's alright. Even if Maruko doesn't give a damn about me..."
>   「そうじゃよ、わたしらは気持ちだけで充分じゃ...」
>   Grandad: "That's right. For us it's the thought that counts.
>   ともぞうとおばあちゃんの声は小さく暗かったが、ヒロシは頓着しない。
>   Narrator: Tomozou and grandma's voice was small and gloomy but Hiroshi didn't care.
>   「ほら、ふたりとも気持ちだけで充分だってさ。ハハハッ。さてと風呂でも入ってくるか」

I have several confusions:
1) Is dad claiming that Maruko doesn't care about him, or is he just talking to Maruko and the subject is an implied "anybody" i.e. "Maruko, even if nobody gives a damn about me..."

2) Does 気持ちだけで充分だ express the meaning "It's the thought that counts"?

My main problem (I think) is the last line. ふたりとも気持ちだけで充分だっ**て**さ。さてと風呂でも入ってくるか.

3a) I'm going to claim that the って in bold is the casual quote marker and there is an implied 言った, so I get "Look! You both said it's the thought that counts right?". Is this correct?

3b) I have no idea what さてと means.

3c) I know 風呂に入る means "to take a bath" but I don't understand what question he is asking here. The best I can do is "Will you start to take even a bath", which is nonsense. My guess is that it should be "Does that (it's the thought that counts) even apply to taking a bath", but I really can't see how that would work.

Comment: Actually I'm confused as to who is saying what, are you sure those are the right people saying those things..?

Comment: @ishikun Not 100% certain. Working out who is saying what has been a constant problem for me throughout this book. I guess thinking about it again the first quote could be the grandad and the second the grandma. That makes more sense with your translation of the first sentence.

Comment: I think it could be grandad, then grandmother, then narrator, then dad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [さてと](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1413577659) means:

> 「さて」は何かをしようとするときに言う語です。

Something that you say when you are trying to begin/start something.

==  As for the understanding questions: ==

1) わしのこと気にしなくても　＝　私のことを気にしなくても（いいです）
--> "Don't (you) worry about me"

2) Yeah, I'd agree with that

3a) I think you're on the right track, the って refers to them talking about not having to worry about them and that it's the thought (that you cared) counts.

3b) Above!

3c) He's kind of using it as way to end the topic, "So I think I'll take a bath then!" or "Why don't we go and take a bath then!" <-- I'm not sure exactly of the context. The か here represents a rhetorical question that he is asking himself not an actual question.

Comment: Really helpful, thanks. I'm still confused about the 風呂でも入ってくるか part though. I'm guessing でも is the "or something" meaning, but why is くる used?

Comment: that's て＋くる as in this [link](http://www.jref.com/forum/threads/%E3%81%A6%E3%83%BB%EF%BC%8B%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F%E3%83%BB%EF%BC%8B%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8B-grammar.49088/)

Comment: And definitely "or something"/something like that meaning for でも

Comment: "I guess I'll **go** take a bath or something". I always get confused with the choice of 'go' and 'come' in these constructions. It's くる because he'll **come** back afterwards, right?

Comment: Yup! :) 'I'll go take a bath (and come back)'

Answer (score 1):

I’m quite ignorant of the contents of the story you are introducing. But 「いいんじゃよ。まる子、わしのことなんて気にしなくても」must be the granddad’s remark. Today’s fathers don’t call themselves in such an oldish way of “わし.” It's the word of 儂ら, our contemporary who are octgenerarians.

To your question:

1. The granddad is saying to Maruko “YOU don’t need to care (too much) about us.”
2. 気持ちだけで充分だ means “We appreciate your thoughtfulness. We can’t be happier.

3.「さてと」 in さてと風呂でも入ってくるか means “Well, by the way”.

For instance；

Q.去年の今ごろあなたは何をしていましたか？- What were you doing around this time last year?

A. さてと、ああ、フランス旅行をしていました - Well. (Let me think about). Ah, I was traveling in France.

3ｃ.風呂でも入ってくるか isn’t an interrogative form. 「か」of 「風呂でも入ってくるか」 is a particle to express a light feeling of choice or self-affirmation of doing something, for instances;

暇なので散髪にでも行ってくる**か** – I’m at leisure. Well, I'd be better to go to have my hair cut.

たまには本でも読んでみる**か** – (I haven’t read books for a while) .Well, let’s read a book sometimes.

さて、このくらいで止めておこう**か** - Well. It’ll be better to stop around here.